# Multiply string vectors in python

Tags: python

I have dynamic number of string vectors, which I need to multiply and create an array of dicts combining all possibilities.

If the input were static, I would do it like this:

```
sth = {
    "param1": ["p1v1", "p1v2"],
    "param2": ["p2v1", "p2v2", "p2v3"],
    "param3": ["p3v1", "p3v2"]
}

param_sets = []

for a_top_val in sth["param1"]:
    for a_val in sth["param2"]:
        for a_bottom_val in sth["param3"]:
            param_sets.append({
                "param1": a_top_val,
                "param2": a_val,
                "param3": a_bottom_val
            })

print(param_sets)
print(len(param_sets))
```

This prints the combined dicts like this:

```
[
    {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
    {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
    {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
    {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
    {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
    {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
    {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
    {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
    {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
    {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
    {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
    {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v2'}
]
```

How do I make the for loops around `sth` dynamic?

Comment: Have you read about the `itertools` library? It has several ways to print all permutations of given lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn every entry in `sth` into a list of key-value tuples. Then you can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the cartesian product of all lists and use that to create your param dictionaries:

```
import itertools as it

sth = {
    "param1": ["p1v1", "p1v2"],
    "param2": ["p2v1", "p2v2", "p2v3"],
    "param3": ["p3v1", "p3v2"]
}

param_tuples = (
    [(param, val) for val in values] for param, values in sth.items()
)

result = [
    dict(param_combination) for param_combination in it.product(*param_tuples)
]
```

result:

```
[{'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
 {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
 {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
 {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
 {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
 {'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
 {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
 {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
 {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
 {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
 {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
 {'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v2'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all combinations of possible values and [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to reapply the keys to the tuples:

```
from itertools import product

sth = {
    "param1": ["p1v1", "p1v2"],
    "param2": ["p2v1", "p2v2", "p2v3"],
    "param3": ["p3v1", "p3v2"]
}

prod = product(*(sth[k] for k in sth))
a = [dict(zip(sth.keys(), p)) for p in prod]

print(a)
```

to get:

```
[{'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
{'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
{'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
{'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
{'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
{'param1': 'p1v1', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
{'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
{'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v1', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
{'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
{'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v2', 'param3': 'p3v2'},
{'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v1'},
{'param1': 'p1v2', 'param2': 'p2v3', 'param3': 'p3v2'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

To loop dictionaries in python you can use

```
for k, v in sth:
    print (k, v)
```